# CS50 PS 1 Greedy

Tags: c, cs50

Looking for some advice about why this is running so strangely.  Everything over `.25` works perfectly, but anything lower than `.25` and I'm getting some really strange results.  What's wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
int v;
int count;
int q= 25;
int d= 10;
int n= 5;
int p= 1;
float m;

do
{ 
    printf("How many coins do you need for this change?:\n");
    m=GetFloat();
}    
while (m<0);


int balance;

m=m*100;
balance= round (m);



while (balance >= q)
{
    v=balance/q;
    count=v;
    balance=balance-(v*q);


}

while (balance >= d)
{
    v=balance/d;
    count=count+v;
    balance=balance-(v*d);

}

while (balance >= n)
{
    v=balance/n;
    count=count+v;
    balance=balance-(v*n);
     printf("%i\n", count);
    printf("%i\n", count);

}

while (balance >= p)
{
    v=balance/p;
    count=count+v;
    balance=balance-(v*p);

}   

printf("Total number of coins needed:%i\n", count);
}
```

Comment: 0.25 for what? What specific values? What strange results?

Comment: @Politank-Z First read, then comment. If you don't understand, don't comment.

Comment: @Xz_awan Incorrect. Comments are an appropriate venue to ask for clarification.

Comment: Yes they are, but you need to read the question first. Not ask for clarification directly. And believe me, this question is quite simple to understand as it stands.

Answer (score 3):

For values lower than 0.25, you never go into the first while section (since balance < q), and therefore count remains uninitialized, leading to undefined results.

Just change -

```
int count;
```

into

```
int count = 0;
```